# Allowing external access through firewall to Django in Windows

Tags: django, windows

I want to allow external access to my website, which is being hosted by Django (development server) on Windows 7. To run the server on port 8000, I enter:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

If I disable the Windows firewall, then this can be accessed externally. However, enabling the firewall means that it cannot be accessed externally.

So, I tried adding an "Inbound Rule" at "Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Advanced Settings". Here, I allowed inbound TCP access via port 8000.

However, my website still cannot be accessed externally. What else do I need to do?

Comment: you should absolutely not be running django in that fashion for anything other than testing and development work.  the runserver directive is not designed to handle much.  Setup a service such as Apache. It may seem like much to install and get going but it will payout dividends down the road to get the experience now.

Comment: May be you forgot to tick the area for your rule. 
... "Domain", "Private" and "Public" ... Check them all.

Comment: Actually, I am running the Django development server.....is this the problem?

Comment: Do you have an outbound rule as well that allows access on port 8000 so that communication may flow both directions?

Comment: I also faced this problem with  Django. I tried a lot and later found that its firewall problem

Answer (score 2):

**Environment Version**
OS：Windows 10
Python：3.9.13
Django：4.0.1

open cmd.exe,then run:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Django Web Server" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=8000 action=allow
```

If your public ip address is 1.1.1.1
settings.py

```
# load production server from .env
ALLOWED_HOSTS        = ['localhost', 'localhost:5085', env('SERVER', default='127.0.0.1'),'1.1.1.1']
```

open cmd.exe,then run the server on port 8000:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: works for windows 10, Django 4.2.8, Python 3.10. Thank you